# How to search JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hello I have 3 DIVs that contain 1,2,3

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div> 
<div>3</div>
```

and have this JSON

```
[{
    "FactoreId:1": "FactoreItems:a, b, c, d, e"
}, {
    "FactoreId:2": "FactoreItems:g,f"
}, {
    "FactoreId:3": "FactoreItems:i, k, h"
}]
```

I want that when I hover over the DIVs that their values are checked.

If DIV contains `1` show the FactoreItems of `"FactoreId:1": "FactoreItems:a, b, c, d, e"`, if it contains `2` show the FactoreItems of `"FactoreId:2": "FactoreItems:g,f"` and so on ....

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Please elaborate on this question a bit more. What do you mean by 'factoreid 1 factoreitems'?

Also, it would be helpful if you posted the HTML with your `div`s.

Comment: Do you get this JSON from another source in this form? If the structure is created by you, I would change the array to an Object and the keys to digits only for easier and more performant access.

Comment: yes, i get this JSON from another source, i want when hover div ,checked if div contain 1 , in JSON,show FactoreId1 FactoreItems.for example when hover <div>1</div> show me (with alert or anything) a, b, c, d, e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted is incorrect, fixed it so "FactoreId" : num, "FactoreItems": "string"

**HTML**

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 //Fixed JSON
 var factore = [{
       "FactoreId": 1, 
       "FactoreItems": "a, b, c, d, e"
   }, {
       "FactoreId": 2,
       "FactoreItems": "g,f"
   }, {
       "FactoreId": 3,
       "FactoreItems": "i, k, h"
   }]
    $('div').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).text("FactoreID : "+factore[$(this).text() -1].FactoreId +"FactoreItems"+ factore[$(this).text()-1].FactoreItems);
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/xyHNJ/1/)

**Explanation**

*factore* : is the array with json

`$(this).text() -1` returns divs number and -1 since array starts from 0

```
factore[$(this).text() - 1] 
// if you mouseover div with text one the result will be factore[0]
// then use .FactoreId to get id value
```

Comment: Can you tell me about the  $('div').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).text("FactoreID : "+factore[$(this).text() -1].FactoreId +"FactoreItems"+ factore[$(this).text()-1].FactoreItems);
   }); ?

Comment: Note there's a hole in the logic here.  You're simply getting the item in the array at that index, rather than looking up the individual item with a "FactoreId" of 1.  If I swap the list so that "FactoreId" 3 is actually output first in the JSON, this breaks and you get the wrong data in the wrong cells.  A more robust solution would be to find the proper array element where "FactoreId" is 1 and return that element of the array.

Comment: @chsh Well, that's true but i don't see any reason of having an unsorted json like that. But yes you are correct there is a hole but not that likley it would be unsorted

Comment: Consider a case where the IDs aren't all sent.  What if your IDs were based on day of the month but we only retrieve a week at a time?  What happens in this solution on the 28th of the month when we only have 7 days' worth of data?  I can't really see a case outside of sample questions like this where this solution would practically work.

Comment: Well, a dynamic created list of items? It doesn't have to be connected to anything special, you could have a JSON array with data listed from 1-infinit and have data in the arrays. like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/c4vtY/